# Mesos - Zookeeper error; Connection Refused

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I've set up Apache Mesos 0.21.2 on a virtual machine. The installation was performed by downloading the sources, compiling it and applying make install.

On another virtual machine I've copied the build directory in order to use it as a slave system.

I wanted to start with a small 'hello world' framework as showed in http://jamesporter.me/2014/11/15/hello-mesos.html

however, when I'm executing the python framework with 
python hello_mesos.py

I get the following log:

```
I1227 19:16:02.790803  1678 sched.cpp:137] Version: 0.21.1
2015-12-27 19:16:02,790:1678(0x7f6b1e3de700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@712: Client      
environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.5
...
2015-12-27 
19:17:09,526:1678(0x7f6b1bf7e700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1697: 
Socket [127.0.0.1:2181] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server   
refused to accept the client
```

What can be the source that triggers this error? Is there any other way to get more information?

Thank you in advance for any hints and
with best regards

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you use a recent Mesos version, 0.21.2 is quite old as 0.26.0 is out. There are also precompiled packages available.

Concerning your actual problem, it appears that either

- ZooKeeper is not started on the host you're trying to execute your framework on
- If you're trying to reach ZK from another host, you need to set the actual IP

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I installed now mesos 0.26.0 based on the instructions given on this webpage:
https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/

I also installed the python eggs:
wget http://downloads.mesosphere.io/master/ubuntu/14.04/mesos-0.26.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
and
easy_install mesos-0.26.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg

However, when I'm trying to use the test-framework (as explained here: http://jamesporter.me/2014/11/15/hello-mesos.html) I now do get the error message:  

ImportError: No module named interface

What the heck is now going wrong?

Comment: Well, the article you're referring to is 13 months old. It is very well possible that it no longer fits to the Mesos API

Comment: Good point! Mhh, where is the Mesos API for python? Using google with the keywords mesos +api +python or even simple mesos +api does not provide any API documentation

Comment: I'm not a Python user, so I can't really give you any hints. What is the goal you're trying to achieve actually? Aside from creating some framework in Python...

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/apache/mesos/tree/master/src/examples/python for the official examples